# Lighttpd rewrite-if-not-file cannot process *php and *html in one rule

Tags: url-rewriting, lighttpd

To enable a shorten-url service, I had to add a rewrite rule to my
lighttpd.conf. This seems to be important, otherwise shortlinks like
http://example.com/Xf6Y would return a 404 error. This is because Xf6Y
is not a file but a shortlink hash.

So I added these lines to my lighttpd.conf:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
  "^/(.*)$" => "/index.php?fwd=$1"
)
```

This works excellently, except for websites that contain a index.html
instead of an index.php.

I tried to duplicate the rewrite rule, like

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
        "^/(.)(\?.)?$" => "/index.php?fwd=$1",
        "^/(.)(\?.)?$" => "/index.html?fwd=$1"
)
```

This resulted in a "duplicate rule" error, so lighttpd is
not able to restart.

Does anyone know how to write a rewrite rule that will redirect index.php and index.html?

Comment: What lines have you duplicated? All the three or only the middle one?

Comment: @D4VID Only the middle one

Comment: That makes sense. The rule is the same for both lines. So `Lighttpd` is not able to choose between the two.